# Prove that the set $A$ is measurable and find its Lebesgue measure.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $A ⊂ [0, 1] × [0, 1]$ be the set of points $(x, y)$ with decimal representations $x = 0.x_1x_2 ..., y = 0.y_1y_2 ...$
such that $x_ny_n = 5$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}.$ Prove that the set $A$ is measurable and find its Lebesgue measure.

Okay so I know the straightforward way do this by taking open sets that go to measure zero.  However I have a slicker proof that seems to almost work.  Let $f(x, y) = 0$ if $(x,y) \notin A,$ and $= 1$ if it is.  Then $m(E) = \int_{I \times I}f(x,y)d(x \times y)$.  It is clear that $\int_I\int_I f(x,y)dxdy = \int_I\int_If(x,y)dydx = 0$.  This is because $x$ determines $y$ and vise versa so there is at most one $x$ for every $y$ so $\int_I\int_I f(x,y)dxdy = \int_I 0 dy$ and the same for the other one.  But, we don't know that $f(x,y)$ is measurable and in fact it is measurable iff $A$ is, so can we actually say anything about $\int_{I \times I}f(x,y)d(x \times y)$?

Thanks

Comment: You proved half: if it is measurable, then the measure is zero.  Now you have to do the other half.

Comment: I know, but I can't think of any way do do it other then just showing the measure is zero strait forward use of the definition, and then that makes this argument useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $x\mapsto x_n$ is measurable for each $n$ (it is ambiguous only on a set of measure zero, so the ambiguity doesn't matter). It follows that the set of $(x,y)$ with $x_ny_n=5$ is measurable for each $n$, and $A$ is a countable intersection of such.

Comment: What do you mean by the map $x \rightarrow x_n$?

Comment: Mapping the real number $x\in[0,1]$ to the $n$th digit in the decimal expansion of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\{(x,y)\in [0,1]:\forall n (\{x_n,y_n\}\subset \{1,5\}) \}.$ $$\text { For each  } n \text { let } B(n)=\{ \sum_{j=1}^{j=n}b_j10^{-j}:b_j\in \{1,5\} \}. $$  Note that $B_n$ has $2^n$ members.For each $x\in B(n)$ let $I(x,n) = (x-10^{-n},x+10^{-n}).$ $$\text { Let } J(n)=\cup_{x\in B(n)}I(x,n).$$ $$\text { For every } n \text { we have }A\subset B\times B\subset J(n)\times J(n).$$ Let $\mu$ denote 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure.$$\text { We have } \mu (J(n)\times J(n))\leq \sum \{ \mu (I(x,n)\times I(y,n) : (x,y)\in B(n)\}=$$ $$=(2\cdot 10^{-n})^2(2^n)^2=2(2/10)^{2n}.$$ $$\text { Letting } n\to \infty \text { we obtain } \mu (A)\leq \mu (B\times B)=0.$$